# I am making a hangman project and I wanted to know how to make the game stop once you finish all your tries?

Tags: java

This is my code that i have written so far. The problem is that when it asks for how many tries and I put 3 it only lets me try 3 times no matter what, even if I guess wrong or right. The tries represent how many times you get the guess wrong. So I if didn't get the word in 3 tries then it would stop the game. That's my problem.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Hangman {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String[] dictionary = loadWords();
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman!");
        System.out.println("How many tries");
        int tries = kb.nextInt();

        String word = chooseWord(dictionary);
        System.out.println("OK, I've choseen my word. Start guessing");
        System.out.println(word);
        boolean[] bool = new boolean[26];
        for(int i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
            String wordguess = kb.next();
            char guess = wordguess.charAt(0);

            processGuess(guess, word, bool);
            printPattern(word, bool);
        }
    }

    // Loads a list of words from a file and returns the lsit as a String[].
    public static String[] loadWords() throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner wordFile = new Scanner(new File("dictionary.txt"));
        String line;
        while (wordFile.hasNextLine()) {
            line = wordFile.nextLine();
            if(!line.equals(""))   
                wordList.add(line);
        }

        String[] result = new String[1];
        return wordList.toArray(result);
    }

    // Takes an array of strings that represents the valid words as a parameter.
    // Chooses one such word randomly and returns it.
    public static String chooseWord(String[] dict) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int numword = r.nextInt(dict.length); 
        String hangword = dict[numword];  
        return hangword;
    }

    // Checks if a player has won the game
    // Returns true only if all letters in the word have been guessed
    public static boolean hasWon(String word, boolean[] guesses) {
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (guesses[word.charAt(i)-'a'] == false){
            return false;
            }
        }    
        return true;
    }

    // Prints out the pattern of letters in the secret word based on the word 
    //    and the letters that have been guessed.
    // Prints any letter that has already been guessed and a _ for a letter that 
    //    has not been guessed.
    public static void printPattern(String word, boolean[] guesses) {
        StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) { 
            if (guesses[word.charAt(i) - 'a']) { 
                pattern.append(word.charAt(i));
            }
            else {
                pattern.append("_");
            }
            pattern.append(" ");
            }

        System.out.println(pattern.toString());
    }

    // Handles a guess by marking the letter as guessed and returns the number of 
    //    tries to be charged: 0 if the guessed letter is in the word and 1 otherwise. 
    public static int processGuess(char guess, String word, boolean[] guesses) {
        if(guesses[(guess - 'a')] == false){
            guesses[(guess - 'a')] = true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("you already guessed that letter");
        }
        return guess;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is either the same user as, or is working on the same project as user1067478.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
```

You are iterating a fixed number of times. Shouldn't it be something like

```
while (!wordComplete && triesCount < tries) {
 //...
```

?

Comment: Would i have to make a separate variable for wordComplete and triesCount and can you help me with the process of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a for loop, you should use a while loop.

I assume you may want to be able to have a variable number of tries rather than just 3. So the example would accommodate that.

Something like this:

```
int incorrectTries = 0;

while (incorrectTries <= tries)
{
    String wordguess = kb.next();
    char guess = wordguess.charAt(0);
    processGuess(guess, word, bool);
    printPattern(word, bool);
}

// Checks if a player has won the game
// Returns true only if all letters in the word have been guessed

public static boolean hasWon(String word, boolean[] guesses) {
for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
if (guesses[word.charAt(i)-'a'] == false){
    incorrectTries++;
    return false;
    }
}   
return true;

}
```

Comment: Thank you should I should input in this in my main method or in the haswon method?

Comment: thanks this code is great but it still doesn't really solve my problem because when it asks for how many tries and i say 10 and i guess all the letters before 10 tries it doesn't stop me. How can i fix it so that when i guess my word before the amount of tries needed the game stops.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the for loop that iterates through the tries, use a while loop that checks to see if tries equals zero. When a bad guess is made, subtract one from tries. That should get you what you need.